# User-defined configurations for Matlab Compiled Projects

Tags: matlab, configuration, matlab-compiler

I am using the Matlab Compiler to compile Matlab code into dlls, which I can run elsewhere. However, my dlls and functions have a lot configuration variables and too many for them all to be an input to the function.

Currently, the user specifies a file path to a .mat file which is loaded within the compiled code for all the configuration settings. A .m file is executed to generate the .mat file. However, when the config settings change, the user must go into the .m file change the necessary settings and re-execute it to generate an updated .mat file.

Obviously, this process is cumbersome and it's easy to forget to re-execute the .m for the config to be updated. A couple things I have considered but seem problematic:

- It'd be great if .mat files could be read/editted with text editor, but as far as I can tell this is not possible
- Another approach is XML, but I am under the impression Matlab does not have great XML support
- Run the .m file to populate the work-space within the compiled dll but this is not possible

So my question is if anyone else has run into this issue before or can think of any other alternative approaches that would be more streamlined than my current approach.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

So you could use XML - MATLAB does have support for XML via `xmlread` and `xmlwrite`. These functions return/accept a DOM node which you will need to manipulate yourself, though, and that can be a bit fiddly. XML is also not that fun for your users to have to edit or read if they want to change the config.

If you weren't using MATLAB Compiler, you could also use a `.m` file directly to store config information. But if you're compiling that won't work as the `.m` file will be encrypted and no longer editable.

I typically use [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) for config files. YAML is a text-based format, so the user will be able to edit them by hand in a text editor and you'll be able to version-control the files; but it's much more human-readable than XML. There are no angle-brackets, it's laid out much more simply, and you can include comments to delimit and explain sections of the config.

MATLAB does not natively support YAML, but there are third-party things that you can download (for example [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yamlmatlab/) or [here](http://vision.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~kyamagu/software/yaml/)) that work well, are easy to integrate, and are freely licensed. I've also written code myself that I'd be happy to share somehow if you need that.